# how to change website image in wordpress when we send site link to anyone

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I send link of this website to anyone then there a dummy image appear but I want my company logo there

The website link is www.nexpeak.com

I wanna change a link in logo header in `Wordpress`, but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: You need to use Open Graph tags for that.

Comment: add this to your header file and wait 1 day for changes : <meta property="og:image" content="https://nexpeak.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/NexPeak.png"/>

Comment: Removed quote block, improved capitalization. Left "wanna".

Comment: #elvin where in header file

Answer (score 0):

Add below code after  and before  in your theme header file

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Nexpeak Software Company - Leading Software House in Pakistan" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://nexpeak.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://nexpeak.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/NexPeak.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nexpeak Software Company - Leading Software House in Pakistan" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Welcome to nexpeak software house. We are professional in software and website development ,Graphics ,SEO ,Android and IOS development and other services." />
```

Comment: hey at where in header file